# How do I make buses and trams run faster than walking speed?

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

In *Cities in Motion 2*, my buses and trams seem to run very slowly, at around 1 km/h.

As can be seen below, the *Length* and *Estimated Duration* values are about the same.

[image: Screenshot of line information]

How do I make the lines run faster than a slow walking speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows estimated duration in game time, while the vehicle speeds are compared to real time.  If I remember correctly, 1 hour in game time on normal speed is 2 minutes in real life time, a 30:1 ratio.  So your vehicles are actually running at about 30-40 km/h.

If the game time speed was in real time, it would literally take 24 hours to play through one game day, which would be a little excessive.

Comment: This sort of makes sense to me but I'm still a bit confused. If the length of the line is in 'game length' and the estimated duration is in 'game time', then isn't the 'game speed' still around 1 km/h ?

Comment: Yes, you're right but that doesn't really matter, as far as gameplay goes.  The vehicles go at a normal looking pace around the map, and the commuters don't seem to care that the bus ride takes "9 hours" of game time.  As long as your route gets them to point A to point B and they don't have to wait forever for the bus/tram/whatever, they're happy.

Answer (score 1):

What roads are your trams running on? Trams move a lot faster if they are on expressways. I tested this by creating three tracks of 2x 450m. [image: 450m]

1: Expressway
2: Pedestrian
3: Regular road

The express way was a lot faster, taking 1m17s vs 1m33s for the other two. This despite being a few meters longer (because you don't have two-way expressways). You can also see it in the travel times reported. For some reason the game also pretends the track is shorter, but as you can see in the screenshot above that is not the case.[image]